# Minecraft connect a bot with offline account to offline minecraft server in python

Tags: python, networking, minecraft, packet

How to send a handshake and login start packet to a Minecraft server with a library socket? I am trying to make a library that allows you to send packets to the Minecraft server. I have seen some tools, but they are hard to understand. Any ideas or code snippets? I also want to ask if I need the encryption key request and respond if I want to connect an offline account to an offline server. I understand that I don't need the client authentication, encryption request, and responses if I want to connect an offline account to the offline Minecraft server, but how then will I get the login success packet from the server? I am confused. I need help. I need the packets and the connection. Mineflayer provides only the connection without giving access to the packets sent and received.

My current code for handshake packet:

```
def send_handshake(sock_con, host, port, version):
    # sock_con is a socket connection from the client to the server ( I use the library "socket" ) 
    handshake_packet = struct.pack(">B", 0x00) + varint.encode(version) + \
                       varint.encode(len(host)) + host.encode('utf-8') + \
                       struct.pack(">H", port) + struct.pack(">B", 0x02)
    print("Handshake Packet Bytes ", handshake_packet)
    sock_con.send(handshake_packet)
```

My currect code for login start packet:

```
def send_login_start(sock_con, name):
    username_bytes = name.encode('utf-8')
    login_start_packet = struct.pack(">B", 0x00) + varint.encode(len(username_bytes)) + username_bytes
    print("Login Packet Bytes ", login_start_packet)
    sock_con.send(login_start_packet)
```

And now I am stuck at the encryption request, the encryption response, and the login success packets. I want to do it in low level networking in python3 by using struct.pack

I tried to look at other tools, but either they are in Java script, which I don't know, or they are confusing. I am trying to connect a bot to a Minecraft server in Python by using packets. Of course, with keep-alive packets, the bot can stay connected. If that works, I will add proxies. The bot and the server are both offline (they are up and running, but the mode is offline). I tried with https://gist.github.com/barneygale/1209061 but it doesn't work.

Comment: *"now I am stuck at the encryption request, the encryption response"* Why? As you said there is no encryption request and response for offline servers.

Comment: *"and the login success packets"* And what exactly is the problem with it?